# css3 rotate animation wont work

Tags: css, animation

I have used css3 animate for small text to rotate but it wont rotate.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwzs026h/)

```
    <h1 class="title">Coming Soon <small>btw learning</small></h1>


      small {
animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
              }

     @-webkit-keyframes spin {
     0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
     20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
     25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
     45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
     50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
     70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
     75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
     100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `display:inline-block;`

```
<h1 class="title">Coming Soon <span class="animation">btw learning</span></h1>


        .title
        {
        font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 100px;
        margin-top: 25%;
        }


      .animation {
          animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
          display:inline-block;
        }

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: why cant i use span tag as i want the text to be inline

Comment: Invalid HTML. A `<div>` element cannot be inside a heading element.

Comment: i replace <div> with <p>@Rob

Comment: you can't use span beacuse it's inline @akash

Comment: can someone please explain why inline won't work is there any way around

Comment: the solutions is to put inline-block as you can see! remember to check the answer as solve! @akash